# How can I make my internet slower?

Tags: ajax

No really.

I have a lot of AJAX requests in my web app, and I want to include appropriate feedback mechanisms, spinners and the like for when the response is slow. But when developing all the calls are almost instant...

Comment: Are you trying to temporarily slow it down so you can see how it behaves when on a slow connection? Or am I missing your point?

Comment: From what i am seeing, is that you are running a server off of your home machine and you want to put an upper limit on your up speed from your webapplications server to the clients who request it?

Comment: Sorry, yes - temporarily slow it down to see how it behaves. And yes - running on my home machine, so not actually internet. Either slow down the server response, or some sort of browser plugin to throttle it or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two software solutions I have found - one for Mac and one for Windows: 
http://wanem.sourceforge.net/
http://mschrag.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

Using setTimeout inside your success handler can be one way. Suppose your callback for ajax completion is say function `doneFn(..)`, then, change that callback to something like `delayedDone(..)` and from there call your original `doneFn` after a delay:

```
function delayedDone(){
    setTimeout(function(){doneFn(responseParams);}, 3000);
}
```

And of course, another way would be to introduce some tiny milliseconds of sleep on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

A rate limiting proxy might be what you're looking for.  http://blog.nella.org/?p=833 shows an example, I'm not sure how complete it is.  But the concept can easily be expanded on.